# Как получить по share code в cs go ссылку на файл .dem

Tags: steam

Есть код от cs go, к примеру такой: **CSGO-SPoap-C6v9x-YXCxz-Pvmpd-9EGZG**

Надо получить файл .dem

Или вытащить статистику по матчу, сам файл то мне не нужен. Нужна статистика.

Как вариант парсить сайт: 
https://csgo-stats.com/match/CSGO-SPoap-C6v9x-YXCxz-Pvmpd-9EGZG

Но что делать, если сайт будет не доступен. Поэтому хотелось бы решение на своих серверах.

P.s. Я знаю что тут был похожий вопрос. Рабочего ответа там так и не дали, поэтому поднимаю его снова.